# Base Case for factorial recursive solution

Tags: factorial

I've looked at many recursive solutions and I don't understand why sometimes the base case is "if(num === 0) return 1;" and other times it is "if(num === 1) return 1;" Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

you should use something along the line of

```
int factstart(int num){
if(num<0) return -1;
else return num * fact(num-1);
}
int fact(int num){
if(num == 0) return 1;
else return num*fact(num-1);
}
```

the reason that people use that people use 1 or 0 is it will get them an answer most of the time, but this isn't defensive programming, and if a negative number is given for either, then the answer will be some random value, and if 0 is given for the case that they have equal to 1 then it will give 0 even though 0 factorial is 1